# Pygame - Change image from image folder on key press

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Here is my code what i have tried so far,

```
filesList = [x for x in os.listdir(".\\images")]
fileNames = [x.split(".")[0] for x in os.listdir(".\\images")]
itemsDict = {k: v for k, v in zip(filesList, fileNames)}
itemList = list(itemsDict.keys())
shuffle(itemList)

for item in itemList:
     image = pygame.image.load(item)

    #Game Loop 
    running = True
    while running:
        # Background Image
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit(0)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    running = False
```

Every time i am breaking game loop to load next image. And also i don't want to use random.choice or choices in Class(sprite), based on key press update images (to avoid repeated image).

Looking for solution like without breaking a loop, having sprite class to update image one by one from folder on key press ( if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:)

Comment: Where is the declaration of the background variable? If you have the images in a list, why not have an index variable such as "count" initialized to 0, blit the image at index count to the screen, and increment the variable when space is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't run multiple while loops in your foreach loop but instead make an image object where you save the current image and on the keypress change that image to the next image.

To get the next image you can use some index variable and count that up